# Match middle and end of length x width x height

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am trying to match, the following cases:

**1.** Get either between or if only one `x` exists the end

Example:

```
| Matches/Cases     | Result |
|-------------------|--------|
| 200 x 90 x 14     | 90     |
| 90x200            | 200    |
| 200 x 90x20       | 90     |
| 60,4 x46,5 x 42,6 | 46,5   |
| 90x190,9          | 190,9  |
```

**2.** Get if two `x` exist the final one, and if only one exist  no result

Examples:

```
| Matches/Cases     | Result |
|-------------------|--------|
| 200 x 90 x 14     | 14     |
| 90x200            | -      |
| 200 x 90x20       | 20     |
| 60,4 x46,5 x 42,6 | 42,6   |
| 90x190,9          | -      |
```

I stuck at getting one specific case! I  tried to match with the following regex `x\s?((\d+(?:,\d+)?))\s?`, but I still get only the last part of the cases like for `90x200` I get `200`, but for `200 x 90 x 14` I get `90 x 14`.

Any suggestions of two regex that works for case 1 or  case 2?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: These are two requirements, right? Why should the same regex match **90** in `200 x 90 x 14` and **14** in the very same string? Additionally, which language are you using?

Comment: For the first: [**`[\d,]+\h*x\h*([\d,]+)(?:\h*x*[\d,]+)?`**](https://regex101.com/r/uC3iN7/1)

Comment: And for the second: [**`[\d,]+\h*x\h*[\d,]+\h*x\h*([\d,]+)`**](https://regex101.com/r/aW2lN7/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to match with the following regex `x\s?((\d+(?:,\d+)?))\s?`, but
>   I still get only the last part of the cases.

Actually by your own RegEx you are going to capture all digits or floats followed by a `x`. So it's not only last part but all similar occurrences.

Solution (main regex):

```
(?: *(\d+(?:,\d+)?) *(?:x|$))
```

If you want it for case #1 then append quantifier `{2}`

```
(?: *(\d+(?:,\d+)?) *(?:x|$)){2}
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uX3uD7/1)

If you want it for case #2 append quantifier `{3}`

```
(?: *(\d+(?:,\d+)?) *(?:x|$)){3}
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uX3uD7/2)

*`m` modifier should be set in both cases*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am using excel as regular expression engine  - http://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/. Hence, the match does not work, as excel can only match and not get groups. Any suggestions how to exactly match the cases?

Comment: The link you provided states it supports capturing groups. So there should be a functionality to work with captured groups as well. @mrquad

Comment: My problem is that I get the wrong string back, like f.ex. `200 x 90 x 14`, I get back `200 x 90 x`  instead of `90`. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Could  you update your question with your code snippet?

Comment: I am using the following regex function for excel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: `inputMatches(0).subMatches(0)` should return **first** capturing group of matched string (which you need it). If not try to play with indexes. Sorry that I'm not a VBScript guy.

Answer (score 1):

Just turning the comments into an answer.
For the first case, you could use:

```
[\d,]+\h*x\h*([\d,]+)(?:\h*x*[\d,]+)?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/uC3iN7/1).

---

And the second:

```
[\d,]+\h*x\h*[\d,]+\h*x\h*([\d,]+)
```

Another [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/aW2lN7/1).

---

***Hint***: Replace `\h` with either `[ ]*` or `\s*` if it is not supported.